# How to confirm ssh fingerprint

Tags: centos, ssh

I work on Windows 10.

I PuTTY ssh into physical:CentOS7, virtualbox:CentOS6,7 & Ubuntu 16.

On 1st ssh FROM Win TO vb:Ubuntu & I get the regular ole server/fingerprint not a known host popup. 
No big deal. But I wondered: how could I confirm there's no "man in the middle" ?

Simplest case: I'm sitting in front of the target (called 'local' from here on) and check its fingerprint directly.

Turns out: trying to local view the public machine key fingerprint using `ssh-keygen -lf <filename>` (file: `/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub`) on the Ubuntu 16 gave me a fingerprint I couldn't match against any warning from a remote ssh.

By anywhere, I mean that:

1. the string `"2048 SHA256:NPAUL **** 4QQ user@example.com (RSA)"` is not what appears in the PuTTy popup and
2. when I copy the pub key file to CentOS6 or 7 and run `ssh-keygen -l -f` against it, they match each other but not the one from running `ssh-keygen` locally on Ubuntu (like, the implementations differ).

   2a. doing the `scp` was just a way I thought I might test things out.

The nut of the question is: how can I confirm the fingerprint ssh ui shows me is correct before I tell it 'yes' I'll accept it?

Local view of fingerprint (approx):
`"2048 SHA256:NPAULv10 **** lic4QQ user@example.com (RSA)"`

Remote view of fingerprint (using Win PuTTy):
`"The new rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 ce:e9:43 **** :cb"`

Remote view of fingerprint (using CentOS6&7 terminal): 
"2048 ce:e9:43 **** :cb" filename (RSA)

Note:

1. The remotely viewed fingerprint has colons in it.
2. The bubblebabble digests (from `-B`) are match but they aren't fingerprints.
3. local `ssh-keygen -lf` on `/etc/ssh*.pub` (i.e.: *dsa_key.pub, *ecdsa_key.pub, *ed25519_key.pub & *rsa_key.pub) didn't output a match for the fingerprint seen remotely either.
4. I've overlookedly something probably, I did check the std man pages, ubuntu docs ... don't know what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-E` switch to the `ssh-keygen`:

```
ssh-keygen -l -f -E md5
```

This is available in recent OpenSSH versions and prints the "old" MD5 fingerprint, same as PuTTY.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went over the std man, ubuntu man... 
I even took a quick look at rfc4716 thinking I might see what I missed but no luck; that md5 looks like magic and the -m wasn't necessary. 
This one really stumped me. Thanks again!

Comment: It is claimed in the following article that 
the -E switch is not available to ssh-keygen before OpenSSH v6.8.

See the section: "Displaying fingerprints in other formats" in:
http://www.phcomp.co.uk/Tutorials/Unix-And-Linux/ssh-check-server-fingerprint.html